# ArcGIS Pro arcade if else statements

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade, if-else

I am tasked with sorting Zoning codes numbering over 100 to just 5 (Residential, Office, Commercial, Industrial and Misc).

For whatever reason I cannot get Arcade to recognize a text attribute other than the first two statements.

[image: ArcGIS Pro Calculate Field in Arcade with If Else Statement]

I've tried the following with no success:

```
if ($feature.ZONE == "C-1"){     
    $feature.ZONE1; 'Commercial'}
else $feature.ZONE1; 'Miscellaneous'
```

I want any Field containing a value "C-" or "CB-" to be Commercial,
"I-" to be Industrial, "R-" residential and "Misc" everything else.

```
var zone = $feature.ZONE;

if (find('C-', zone,0)>0) {

return 'Commercial'
};

if (find('O-', zone,0)>0) {
return 'Office'

};
if (find(['R-',"X-","SH","SR"], zone,0)>0) {
return 'Residential'

};
else {
return 'Misc'
};
```

Am I just using the wrong processing tool?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way for sorting the Zoning codes. It seemed like a very tedious way of doing the script, but it worked. I was hoping for a way of combining variables to one line.

```
    var zone = $feature.ZONE;

    if (zone == 'C-1') {
    return 'Commercial'
    }
    else if (zone == 'C-2') {
    return 'Commercial'
    }
    else if (zone == 'C-3') {
    return 'Commercial'
    }
    else if (zone == 'CB-1') {
    return 'Commercial'
    }

    else {
    return 'Misc'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost all languages, if not all, have a construct for handling these types of situations better than large `else-if` statements.  For Arcade, it is the [`When`](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/logical_functions/#when) statement:

> **When**
>
> When(expression1, result1, [expression2, result2, ..., expressionN, resultN]?, defaultValue) -> [Any](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/types/#any)
>
> Evaluates a series of conditional expressions until one evaluates to true.

Since Arcade is a young-ish language, it continues to evolve with new [releases](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/release-notes/) happening every few months on average.  I point that out because it is really important to state what version of ArcGIS and Arcade software is being used since code written with newer functions won't run on older versions.

```
// Using original Arcade functions
var zone_codes = [
    "C-3", "C-1", "C-2", "R-3", "0-3", "C-2", "CB-1", "I-1"
];

var zone_groups = [];
for(var i in zone_codes) {
    var z = Split(zone_codes[i], "-", -1)[0];
    zone_groups[i] = When(
        IndexOf(["C", "CB"], z) > -1, "Commercial",
        IndexOf(["I"], z) > -1, "Industrial",
        IndexOf(["R"], z) > -1, "Residential",
        "Miscellaneous"
    );
    z = "";
};
return zone_groups;


// Using newer Arcade (1.12+) functions
var zone_codes = [
    "C-3", "C-1", "C-2", "R-3", "0-3", "C-2", "CB-1", "I-1"
];
var zone_groups = [];

for(var i in zone_codes) {
    var z = Split(zone_codes[i], "-", -1)[0];
    Push(zone_groups, When(
        Includes(["C", "CB"], z), "Commercial",
        Includes(["I"], z), "Industrial",
        Includes(["R"], z), "Residential",
        "Miscellaneous"
    ));
    z = "";
};
return zone_groups;
```

Returns `["Commercial","Commercial","Commercial","Residential","Miscellaneous","Commercial","Commercial","Industrial"]`

Answer (score 0):

Old post... But in my small test the logical OR operator || works.
https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/logic/#operators

```
var line = $feature.FeatureCategory

if (line == "Shrub" || line == "Timber Shrub") {
return "Shrub"}
else {
return "Timber"}
```